# Deleting commits from remote branch in Git

Tags: git

I need to delete commits from a remote branch. I created a new branch, used `git rebase` to delete the unwanted commits, but when I try to commit the rebase I get `nothing to commit, working tree clean`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show your complete commands?

Comment: `git checkout -b pull_request` 
  `git rebase -i <commit>`

Comment: OK, that's all you need to do. If you do a forced push, your unwanted commits should be gone

Comment: That didn't work, but I now "fixed" the problem by just creating a new remote branch from the rebased local branch and deleting the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Select how many commits you want to delete from Head, count that revision level, and add beside Head at number place in below command and force push in the next step.

git reset --hard HEAD~3

git push --force